# How to use my own vgg19 file instead of downloading

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
vgg = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
vgg.trainable = False
```

I have this file already downloaded on my PC, how to use that, since I don't want to download again? What will be the alternate code to use the vgg19 weights file I have?

Comment: Please take a look here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

Comment: @silentsudo thanks

Comment: Take a look at here https://keras.io/api/applications/. Try to locate your model into ` ~/.keras/models/` folder

Comment: @dothuan thanks, it's helpful. u can write an answer it would beneficial for others also.

Comment: @cgDude I wrote the answer, please upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at here [keras.io/api/applications](https://keras.io/api/applications/). Try to locate your model into `~/.keras/models/` folder

Please make sure that your model has the same architecture with Keras's model